# Upgrade IOS device to specified version

Tags: ios

I want to upgrade some of the testing devices to specific iOS version (say 5.0 - 5.2), so I can test the App in different environments, but using Apple iTunes only allow us to upgrade the devices to the latest one (6.0), does anyone know if there is any way to do this?

Comment: This is not a programming related question, belongs on something like [Apple.SE]

Comment: This absolutely is a programming question. These petty "You didn't ask the question exactly right" closing of questions, a form of bullying, is exactly why Stack Overflow has such a negative reputation among professionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the the .ipsw you want. There is usually sites out there that store them for users to download. IE: http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

You will then open iTunes and and click the iOS Device, then press 'Option' + click upgrade (Mac) or 'SHIFT' + click upgrade(PC). This will allow you to select the .ipsw you want to install.

Comment: Thank you for being helpful. Real programmers need to know this information.

Comment: I don't believe this will work anymore, as Apple only "signs" the latest version, and iTunes only allows upgrades to "signed" versions.